Questions on components and modules in Angular 17
Im new to Angular and just started a new Angular 17 project (17.3.7). Im confused on how to create modules for specific things. Eg. history module, view history page, history form page etc... From what i know so far, module is a collection of components and i can create components with ng generate component <name>.
My questions are:

when i generate module with ng generate module <name>, does it only generate one page with all the components. If so, how do i generate multiple 'page' for the history module
If i have a lot of components, wont the app/ directory be full of folders of components if i generate with the command mentioned. Can i not just add the components into the module directly


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you are using ng17 you can use standalone components.
To get rid off mess, try to structure your components.
For example
History

Page 1
Page 2
Page N

And then use routing to load components lazily.

@AntonLee standalone components does solve some problems I faced. thx for the info

SO is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. It's not a numbered list of questions site. If you have multiple questions, they need to be in separate posts. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

If you are using ng17 you can use standalone components. To get rid off mess, try to structure your components. For example History - Page 1 - Page 2 - Page N And then use routing to load components lazily.
